# the transition duration does not work on the child when the div is hovered

Tags: html, css, web

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Transitions</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div>hi potter
      <p>Hi Prajith.</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

---

```
p
{
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}


div:hover p
{

    display: block;
}
```

in this code the is like to display the p when the div is hovered and want it smooth to happen to I place a transition duration but does not work can anyone give the solution

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transition the display property. You would need to use opacity to achieve that effect.

```css
p {
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

div:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>hi potter
  <p>Hi Prajith.</p>
</div>
```